# Learning Objective-C and I'm having problems with this snippet of code: (scanf)

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, scanf

I'm learning Objective-C and I'm having problems with this snippet of code: (`scanf`)

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        double xnumber;

        scanf("%1f",&xnumber);

        printf("%f",xnumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this simple program, I cannot set the value of `xnumber` to anything. It alway returns zero no matter what I typed. This basic program it is just an input needed for many exercises... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "l" modifier to indicate you're reading a double

> scanf("%lf", &xnumber);

Comment: Thanks. In the book that I am reading the the lowercase "L" looks like a number "1"!!!

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%1f",&xnumber);` you read a double,so change %1f to %lf.

you can read this http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html

Comment: Thanks. In the book that I am reading the the lowercase "L" looks like a number "1"!!!